# How to get a list of all added subdirectories in CMake

Tags: cmake

In CMake Subdirectories can be added using `add_subdirectory()`.
How can I get the list of all subdirectories that have been added in CMake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace every call with a call to your own function, e. g. `add_and_store_subdirectory()` which adds the directory to a global variable.

Comment: Meaning that add_and_store_subdirectory() is defined somewhere, right?

Comment: @Amani Yes. What I meant was that you would need to [define this function](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/function.html) yourself.

Answer (score 4):

CMake 3.7 has a [`SUBDIRECTORIES` property](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/prop_dir/SUBDIRECTORIES.html) on the directories. For example, to get all the subdirectories of `DIRNAME`:

```
get_directory_property(subdir_list DIRECTORY ${DIRNAME} SUBDIRECTORIES)
foreach(subdir ${subdir_list})
  message(STATUS "${subdir}")
endforeach()
```

Using this approach there is no need to define a custom function for addig subdirectories.